# How can I open a new window on top of any other with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, browser, window.open

If you open a window like this and open a notepad at the same time, new window will open below the notepad.

I'd like to know how to open a new window on top of any other windows. Adding a `window.focus()` is not working..

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('http://google.com', 'google new window', 'width:10');
    }, 5000);
```

[image: openning window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
window.open(url, "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=800, height=900, top=10, left=10");
```

> The open() method creates a new secondary browser window, similar to
>   choosing New Window from the File menu. The strUrl parameter specifies
>   the URL to be fetched and loaded in the new window. If strUrl is an
>   empty string, then a new blank, empty window (URL about:blank) is
>   created with the default toolbars of the main window.
>
> Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When window.open()
>   returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching
>   of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block
>   finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the
>   referenced resource are done asynchronously.

```
var windowObjectReference;
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";

function openRequestedPopup() {
      windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.cnn.com/", "CNN_WindowName", strWindowFeatures);
    }


var windowObjectReference;

    function openRequestedPopup() {
      windowObjectReference = window.open(
        "http://www.domainname.ext/path/ImageFile.png",
        "DescriptiveWindowName",
        "resizable,scrollbars,status"
      );
    }
```

> If a window with the name already exists, then strUrl is loaded into
>   the existing window. In this case the return value of the method is
>   the existing window and strWindowFeatures is ignored. Providing an
>   empty string for strUrl is a way to get a reference to an open window
>   by its name without changing the window's location. On Firefox and
>   Chrome (at least), this only works from the same parent, ie. if the
>   current window is the opener of the window you try to get an handle
>   on. Otherwise the call to window.open() will just create a new window.
>
> To open a new window on every call of window.open(), use the special
>   value _blank for strWindowName.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code. I think it might help you.

```
window.open('http://google.com' ,'_blank', "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=700,left=700,width=600,height=800");
```